# Посоветуйте Modbus эмулятор

Tags: java, эмулятор, rs232, modbus

Посоветуйте Modbus эмулятор, мне надо тестово приконектиться из master к slave и получить регистры из slave по протоколу Modbus RTU, подключение через интерфейс rs-232.

Comment: http://plc-blog.com.ua/devemu_emulator_modbus возможно, стоит попробовать?

Comment: Вообще, по запросу полно ссылок с описаниями: https://yandex.ru/search/?text=Modbus%20rs-232%20emulator

Comment: Да что не начну качать - то антивирус блокирует, то не открывается порт, вот и спрашиваю на проверенные.

Comment: Скачал я Modbus Slave эмулятор, по идее я должен симулировать подключенный ком порт, ок, посмотрел в диспетчер устройств там уже com1 занят, пытаюсь создавать коннект com2, пишет - "Port 2 not avaliable" и сижу я думаю, может мне вместо эмулятора Slave надо Master качать ?

Comment: У Вас система будет "слушать" контроллер-сервер, который обозначается как slave. (Сервер - ведомый, клиент - (Ваше приложение) - ведущий. Странно на первый взгляд, но вот такое обозначение.) Значит и эмулятор вам нужен - slave.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, вы мне очень помогли!

Answer (score 0):

Я перепробовал много инструментов и могу с полной уверенностью посоветовать продукты компании modbustools: modbus poll и modbus slave.

Доступны на оффициальном сайте 
https://www.modbustools.com/download.html